# pd.to_datetime with timestamp and PM

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm trying to convert an object series into a date using pd.to_datetime. However, I keep getting an error.

Example line:
**09/12/2015 09:26:32 PM**

I'm trying:

```py
df.creation_date = pd.to_datetime(df.creation_date, format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: What's with the &Y in your format?

Comment: There is a typo its ``%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p``